# Some images suddenly not appearing

Tags: images

I'm having trouble with some images not showing up. These were fine and then suddenly stopped working for no apparent reason.  A couple of examples:

http://coachmi.com.au/blog/2012/11/how-to-build-a-strong-organisational-culture/

http://coachmi.com.au/blog/2012/11/the-path-creating-your-mission-statement-for-work-and-life-book-review/

I've tried deleting and reinserting the images but it doesn't seem to make any difference.  The images appear in the dashboard when I am editing the post but not when it's previewed or published

Any suggestions/help would be appreciated!

Comment: What are the names of the images that do not show up on those pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at your links, looks like you are using Jetpack which puts all your images on the WordPress CDN. For some reason it is not working correctly. Turn it off and it shall work properly.

Most likely you must have changed the image after publishing the post